# Xcode Playgrounds: Source files are unable to be accessed by each other

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, access-levels

I am creating a playground in Xcode and I do not understand why the "Sources" files cannot talk to each other. I am using SpriteKit which means it is ideal to have one swift file per scene, in my case I have one scene per level. I cannot use a quick workaround and add everything into one massive file... there has to be a better way. Both classes for the two swift files are public. You should be able to access them. Thanks!

I get this error when I try to an object from one class, LevelScene, in the other class TitleScene.

After this

`let levelScene = LevelScene(fileNamed: "LevelScene")`

This happens

`Cannot find 'LevelScene' in scope`

I am aware of this post. This solution still does not work for me.

[Xcode playgrounds can't access swift files in Sources folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29637444/xcode-playgrounds-cant-access-swift-files-in-sources-folder)

I am on Xcode 12.4.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a misunderstanding of playgrounds. There is just one playground. The Sources files are libraries available to the playground — not to each other.

Comment: I have put everything in one source file. I still do not understand this logic given the answer from the question I linked up there. I could have sworn I had access control before this version came out. (Xcode 12.4). Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare all your classes/struct in each file as `public`.
So, if you have defined a struct like this in a file:

```
struct Node {
  var id: Int
}
```

You need to declare is like so:

```
public struct Node {
  var id: Int
}
```

Then your code should work. You can use a struct from one file in another file as long as you declare them as public. Similar concept goes for any functions/methods inside those structs/classes. Even with this solution, you may find Xcode 12.4 complaining about not finding the type in scope. That, I believe, is a known bug. I have the same bug on my Xcode 12.4. I am able to build and run the code even with that error.