# swift playground can't find any type

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm new to swift playground, and I tried to create a instance of Type like Scene or Graphic. But every time I try it keep saying  `cannot find 'Scene' in scope` or `cannot find 'Graphic' in scope.`
[image]

What I am missing here?
Thanks

Comment: Is graphic a custom type you built yourself? If yes, where is it declared? If no, did you forget to import the appropriate framework?

Comment: In the default file in Playground called 'Blu's Adventure', in main code section they declared just like 'let blu = Graphic(image:n )'. without declaring new types or importing any stuff. Maybe the Type called Graphic doesn't exist  in swift but made to work in the  'Blu's Adventure' to teach how type and instance work

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Xcode 12.5 beta, try to enable `import App types` from the right menu (you can open the right menu using the top right corner button). I *think* that should solve the problem, but i could be wrong.
Also [read this answer by Vitali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29711367/11837341)